# How to match user input with object properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, input, properties

I have given some objects various properties. And then I want to display the objects with properties that match user input:

```
Car = Struct.new( :model, :color, :number_doors)

matrix = Car.new( matrix, blue, 4)
fit = Car.new( fit, silver, 2)
volvo = Car.new( volvo, silver, 4)

cars = [matrix, fit, volvo]

puts "What color car do you want?"
response = gets.chomp

# something like 
# if response == cars[X].color
# puts "We have #{cars[X].model} available
```

Comment: First of all, you must notice that `matrix`, `blue`, `fit`, `silver`, `volvo`... all these parameters should be strings ('matrix') or symbols (:matrix). The way it is now your definition of matrix, for instance, depends on itself in a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" including the linked pages, especially the long but very useful http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. We don't care if you're new, we want well-asked questions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you create your `Car` instances correctly:

```
matrix = Car.new(:matrix, :blue, 4)
```

You can then use `Array#any?` method to check if any element of an array evaluates to true:

```
cars.any? { |car| car.color.to_s == response }
# returns true or false
```

So, your code would become:

```
puts "We have #{cars[x].model} available" if cars.any? { |car| car.color.to_s == response }
```

Comment: In this case, to have a complete response, you should show the OP how to create a model Car. If you run the code as you showed the OP you'd get cars.rb:8:in <main>': uninitialized constant Car (NameError), because Ruby won't recognize any object named Car` unless you previously defined it somewhere. The OP said he is a noob, then it is better not to assume he knows how to create the Car instances, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should pass parameters as `String` to create object.

- `matrix = Car.new('matrix', 'blue', 4)`
- `fit = Car.new('fit', 'silver', 2)`
- `volvo = Car.new('volvo', 'silver', 4)`

Code to produce desired output would be similar to what you wrote.

```
       (0...cars.length).each do |x|
         if response == cars[x].color
            puts "We have #{cars[x].model} available"
         end
       end
```

Comment: In this case, to have a complete response, you should show the OP how to create a model `Car`. If you run the code as you showed the OP you'd get `cars.rb:8:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Car (NameError)`, because Ruby won't recognize any object named `Car` unless you previously defined it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First let's make clear that these parameters (`matrix`, `blue` etc) must be strings or symbols. The way it is they are variables and, as they weren't previously defined them, you'll get some `Undefined variable XXX` errors for your code.

Besides, when you write something like:

```
matrix = Car.new( matrix, blue, 4)
```

your have a cyclic definition, since the `matrix` being defined outside depends on a previous definition of `matrix` inside.

Your code should be something like:

```
cars = [ { model: 'matrix', color: 'blue', doors: 4}, {model: 'fit', color: 'silver', doors: 2}, { model: 'volvo', color: 'silver', doors: 4} ]

puts "What color car do you want?"
response = gets.chomp

cars.each{ |car| puts "We have #{car[:model]} available" if car[:color] == response }
```

Notice that you don't need to assign a name for each car available. This would be impossible if the available cars were read from a large database, while in this solution above (with an array of hashes to store cars' data) this wouldn't be a problem.

This leads to a 'big picture advise': **Don't ever think about hardcoding things that may change.**

In this case, if you ever think about a real application based on this code, how would you maintain your cars updated, having to manually insert each new car and, worst of all, find a different name for the instance of it?

This way I presented above, if your cars are read from a database you'll just write something like:

```
cars = get_cars_data
```

where get_cars_data is a method to read the database. The only requirement is that this method returns each car as a hash with `:model`, `:color` and `:doors` keys.